# How to set dashboard as first screen after login in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native where my first screen is Welcome screen and I want to set dashboard on my first screen when the user is login.

Here is my code:

```
componentWillMount(){
    var self = this;
    AsyncStorage.getItem(AppStrings.contracts.IS_LOGGED_IN).then((json) =>{
        try{
            var userDetail =   JSON.parse(json);
            if(userDetail.isLoggedIn != undefined && userDetail.isLoggedIn == true){
                Actions.dashboard();
            }
        }catch(e){
        }
    })
}
```

I set this code on the Welcome screen and its working fine in IOS. But in android issue is it shows the Welcome screen for 5 to 10 seconds before going to dashboard screen when the user is login.

Here I am using react-native-router-flux for the navigation bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `AsyncStorage.getItem()` is asynchronous, your `render()` function is being called BEFORE it has been fulfilled.

So the flow of your application is:

1. Call `componentWillMount()`
2. `AsyncStorage.getItem()`
3. `render()` - This is where you see your Welcome Screen for 5-10 seconds
4. AsyncStorage has been fulfilled - `.then()` and then the User gets redirected to the dashboard.

I would set an `isLoaded` flag in your state:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    isLoaded: false,
  }
}
```

Then inside of your `componentWillMount()` function, set the value to `true` once AsyncStorage has fulfilled its Promise.

```
try {
  var userDetail =   JSON.parse(json);
  if(userDetail.isLoggedIn != undefined && userDetail.isLoggedIn == true){
    Actions.dashboard();
  }
  this.setState({ isLoaded: true });
}
```

And finally, I would add some sort of loading indicator inside of `render()` to show the User that your application is still performing some logic.

`render() {
  if(this.state.isLoading) {
    return <Text>I am loading</Text>
  } else {
    return ...
  }
}`